# Extend colors in React Navigation default themes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, themes, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation Default and Dark themes in my app. A user can change theme thanks to a Switch button, all working fine.

Now I would like to add additional colors to the default and dark themes.
So by default they have something like:

```
Object {
  "background": "rgb(1, 1, 1)",
  "border": "rgb(39, 39, 41)",
  "card": "rgb(18, 18, 18)",
  "notification": "rgb(255, 69, 58)",
  "primary": "rgb(10, 132, 255)",
  "text": "rgb(229, 229, 231)",
}
```

What I would like to do is to append something like:

```
"commentText": "rgb(200, 200, 100)"
```

I am currently calling the themes in this way:

```
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
const { colors } = useTheme();
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
      fontSize: 16,
      color: colors.text,
    },
  });

// in my component ...

<Text style={styles.text}>Date format</Text>
```

What would be the best approach for that? Do I need to entirely define my own custom themes, containing the original colors plus mine? Any way to simply append to the original ones?

**UPDATE:**

I have partly followed [this guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/structure-for-styling-in-react-native) and also decided to create my own themes and add more entries (not visible in this post).
Now my current challenge is to move the color definition directly in the files where my styles are defined (e.g. `typography.js`). It works fine if I use a defined color (e.g. `border: "#d8d8d8"`) but I would like it to pick up the theme (e.g. `color: colors.text`).

The problem is that `useTheme()` can only be called in a React function component or custom React Hook function.
How can I make use of this in `typography.js` for instance?

Code provided below, mind the comments.

`Home.js`

```
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";

import { borders, buttons, layout, typography } from "../styles";

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {

  const { colors } = useTheme();

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: colors.background  // Works fine
    },
    buttonText: {
      ...typography.buttonText,
      color: colors.text,      // I would like to move this to typography.js
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>blabla</Text>
        // More code here....
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

`./styles/index.js`

```
import * as themes from "./themes";
import * as typography from "./typography";

export {
  themes,
  typography
};
```

`./styles/themes.js`

```
export const MyDefaultTheme = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    background: "#f2f2f2",
    border: "#d8d8d8", 
    card: "#ffffff", 
    notification: "#ff3b30",
    primary: "#007aff", 
    text: "#1c1c1e", 
  },
};

export const MyDarkTheme = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    background: "#010101", 
    border: "#272729", 
    card: "#121212",
    notification: "#ff453a", 
    primary: "#0a84ff", 
    text: "#e5e5e7", 
  },
};
```

`./styles/typography.js`

```
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native"; // // This isn't working
const { colors } = useTheme(); // This isn't working

export const textHeader = {
  fontWeight: "bold",
  fontSize: 30,
  textAlign: "center",
  marginBottom: 20,
};

export const buttonText = {
  fontSize: 14,
  textAlign: "center",
  color: colors.text  // This is not working 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [Appearance API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance). The limitation being you're encouraged to use inline styles as the theme may change e.g. switching from day to night.

In your example code you're calling useTheme() outside of the component so it's not going to work. You're original solution of inlining the color style seems to be exactly what the React Native team recommend.

Answer (score -3):

You need to store one Value in Redux and on the basis of this Value you can change every component color by getting this value in every component.
Just dispatch action in App.js and apply custom color on the basis of value stored in redux.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(({ colorScheme }) => {
        if (colorScheme === 'light') {
            dispatch(setMode(false));
        } else {
            dispatch(setMode(true));
        }
    });
    return () => subscription && subscription.remove();
}, []);
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Redux, I am not using it so far. I have read about it, but is that really the way to go? Seems like an overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption that Redux is in the code base.